# A tool to uncompress Windows LZNT1 format

Tags: windows

I have some binary data that is compressed with Microsoft's [LZNT1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj665697.aspx) compression.

Apparently it can be decompressed by calling [**RtlDecompressBuffer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552191(v=vs.85).aspx) ntdll API.

But is there an easier way to decompress it, without having to write an app?

Comment: Have you tried using 7-zip? It seems to support LZ77 and WIM files, of which LZNT1 is a variant.

Comment: Yes, no cigar with 7-zip.

Comment: Ok I ended up writing one myself ([link](https://github.com/rustyx/unpack_lznt1)).

Comment: @RustyX your last comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find anything so ended up writing one myself ([link](https://github.com/rustyx/unpack_lznt1)).